# Shell32.dll is missing, causing black Windows

Tags: windows-7, themes, winpe, shell32.dll

While installing a custom theme for Windows 7 I had to replace shell32.dll in the system32 folder. I renamed the original file to shell32.dll.bak, but when I uninstalled the theme I must only have deleted the theme's shell32.dll and have forgotten to rename shell32.dll.bak to shell32.dll. Thus explorer.exe doesn't work, and when I boot Windows I only get a black screen together with a moveable mouse cursor.

I need a way to either

1. Rename the original file back to shell32.dll
2. Undelete the shell32.dll from the theme, so Windows will work, and I can swap the file names

I have tried to follow [this guide](https://4sysops.com/archives/build-a-bootable-windows-pe-3-0-usb-drive-with-rescue-tools-part-1/) to create a WinPE with recovery tools, but I get "Subsystem needed to support the image type is not present" with PStart on my Alienware M14x R2, and AOMEI PE Builder doesn't support the computer I borrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to check your Windows files for consistency and attempt to repair them:

- **Microsoft's System File Checker** (offline)

  Run `sfc /scannow` in a command prompt as administrator.
- **Microsoft's System Update Readiness Tool** (online)

  [Download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20858) and run it.

They will compute hashes of your files. If they mismatch they will attempt to restore the correct file from respectively an offline or online copy. This should help you get the correct file back.

Comment: The option to repair from the advanced boot options (F8) fails, because "The boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible." CMD from the Windows installation DVD only accesses X:, not C:.

Comment: Do I have to "upgrade" from Win7 to Win7, or what files does it replace?

Comment: Boot into safe mode with command prompt.

Comment: Genius! I could access CMD, and from there I just used rename, and now it works :D